# How to debug Thunderbird LDAP

Tags: thunderbird, ldap

I am trying to configure Thunderbird address book to use my LDAP server. I believe I have filled in the details correctly. However, searches return no results, and if I use the "Download now" button it says "replication failed".

To try to debug this, I followed [these instructions](https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:LDAP_Address_Books#LDAP_Logging) to turn on LDAP logging. However, the log file contains nothing useful:

> 0[1111140]: unbinding
>     0[1111140]: unbound
>   0[1111140]: unbinding
>   0[1111140]: unbound

Hence my question: how do I debug LDAP in Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1):

My approach was to look at the other end, the server. You can enable logging by first stopping the slapd daemon (`sudo service slapd stop` if you are on a Debian-based system), then run the daemon from the command line: `sudo slapd -d stats`, which dumps a whole lot of debugging information to stdout. (Alternatively `sudo slapd -d BER` to dump the packets, [ref.](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/slapdconfig.html))

Using this approach, I realized that Thunderbird never even attempted to connect with my OpenLDAP server.

In my case, the problem was with my SSL certificates. I have set up my own CA to generate certificates that are signed by a root certificate that I import on the client computers (mostly family).

Two things (at least) are crucial:

1. Import the root CA (or the server's certificate, if it is self-signed) into Thunderbird (Options -> Advanced -> Certificates -> View Certificates).
2. Make sure you have correctly generated your certificate. For example, I  had recently put `basicConstraints = CA:TRUE` into the `[ usr_cert ]` section of my OpenSSL config file, in order to be able to import the certificates on an Android device -- afterwards, Thunderbird no longer looked up my addresses... Re-generating the certificates with `basicConstraints = CA:FALSE` immediately solved the problem!

Hope this helps a bit.